# How to change screen orientation of another application

Tags: android, screen-orientation

Is it possible to set the screen orientation of an activity of a different application?

My app invokes other apps in the device. It uses `android:Orientation="sensor"` in all the activities. If auto rotation is disabled and I use my app in landscape, the other apps that are invoked from my app don't take the orientation as that of mine. How can I do this?

I tried changing the system settings using

```
Settings.System.putInt(resolver, Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION,1);
```

But this could change the overall system in case of crash of my app before turning it off, so I don't want this.

Comment: I think it's impossible at the moment. It's my experience, I don't have any link to documentation.

Comment: @Anh3Saigon: I do think it is possible.An app called 'Set Orientation'  (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.setorientation&hl=en)   does exactly that.It presets the screen orientation of the android device.So if the user selects the mode as 'landscape',then all the apps will open in the landscape mode.

Comment: @Ramyavjr: Were you able to find the soln? Even I want to achieve the same.

Answer (score -1):

used these in android manifext.xml under activity

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"

android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```